# CAL and SETRANGE

Tags: navision

Can someone recommend how can I search range  from code

```
Employee : 
ID (CODE)   NAME (TEXT)
001         AAAA
002         BBBB
031         CCCC
1000        DDDD
2000        EEEEE
3000        FFFFF
3001        GGGG
```

I want to range of Employee from 3000 to 4000 ID from Emplyee table , 
I have follow Piece of code in CAL

```
Emplyee.SETRANGE (ID, FORMAT(3000), FORMAT(4000) );
AreaCodeRec.FINDFIRST()
```

This return following record

```
031  --- CCCC
3000 --- FFFF
3001 --- GGG
```

I am not expecting 031 record in above but I guess it is there  because ID is CODE.
Can anybody recommend how can I find A range of biginteger from CODE ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Create new field of integer type and filter on it.